React Native 0.74.3 crashes when the app starts on Android 14 with Display over App enabled
package.json
{
  "name": "Picky_Assist",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^11.3.5",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native/gradle-plugin": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.10.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.2.3",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-battery-optimization-check": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "Camera",
    "MediaLibrary",
    "Microphone",
    "Notifications",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "PhotoLibraryAddOnly"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.8",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.85",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4",
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": {
      "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
    }
  }
}

android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = '1.9.22' 
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
    }
}

Androidmanifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROJECT_MEDIA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />



    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">


      
<!-- React Native Notifications -->
<!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_background"
            android:value="false"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.channel_create_default"
                    android:value="false "/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.default_notification_icon"
                    android:resource="@drawable/notificationsmicon"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" 
                    android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <!-- Firebase Performace monitoring -->
        <meta-data  android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
                    android:value="true" />
    

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver"
                  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<service
    android:name="com.pickyassist.tb.OverlayView.OverlayService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.pickyassist.tb.HeadlessJs" />

        <service
            android:name=".NetworkChangeService"
            android:exported="false" />



        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverHelper"  android:exported="true" >
             <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_CALL" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                 <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                 <action android:name="com.pickyassist.tb.ACTION_TRIGGER_ALARM" />
                 <action android:name="com.pickyassist.SOME_ACTION" />
             </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>

"React Native 0.74.3 crashes when the app starts on Android 14 with Display over App enabled."
i will provided my react native codes above and the version is latest 0.74.3
This problem only occurs with Android 14, and the app works when the display over the app is disabled.
Logcat from the terminal
"07-26 12:11:50.254   892   968 E OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter: Retrieving snapshot for com.google.android.gms.phenotype failed
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Task
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at cfsz.o(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):6)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwch.e(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwch.j(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwch.k(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwch.j(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):8)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwch.k(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwch.j(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):8)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwch.h(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at bwel.c(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):4)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.sync.HeterodyneSyncTaskChimeraService.d(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):77)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.sync.HeterodyneSyncTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):10)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at avzs.call(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):4)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at aced.c(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):6)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at aced.run(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):7)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at acjn.run(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
07-26 12:11:51.626  6650  6707 E PhenotypeFlagCommitter:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
07-26 12:11:51.957  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.games [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:51.958  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.maps#com.google.android.gms [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:51.959  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.cast [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:51.960  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.mobile_data_plan [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:51.961  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.udc [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:51.963  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.vision [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:52.860  5376  7398 E BugleRcsEngine: [142] brfg.a: DroidGuardLogger: Could not create DroidGuard token creation event
07-26 12:11:52.901  7411  7411 E ocessService0:0:
Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
07-26 12:11:53.679   533  4036 E TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
07-26 12:11:54.159   892   968 E OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
07-26 12:11:54.336  7341  7451 E OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
07-26 12:11:54.412  7341  7451 E OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.pickyassist.tb, PID: 7341
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.pickyassist.tb.OverlayView.OverlayService: android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException:
Starting FGS without a type  callerApp=ProcessRecord{e8d72cd 7341:com.pickyassist.tb/u0a190} targetSDK=34
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4664)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleCreateService(Unknown Source:0)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2264)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException: Starting FGS without a type  callerApp=ProcessRecord{e8d72cd 7341:com.pickyassist.tb/u0a190} targetSDK=34
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException$1.createFromParcel(MissingForegroundServiceTypeException.java:53)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException$1.createFromParcel(MissingForegroundServiceTypeException.java:49)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal(Parcel.java:4870)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:4852)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3052)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:6761)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:775)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at com.pickyassist.tb.OverlayView.OverlayService.startMyOwnForeground(OverlayService.java:102)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at com.pickyassist.tb.OverlayView.OverlayService.onCreate(OverlayService.java:54)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4651)
07-26 12:11:54.490  7341  7341 E AndroidRuntime:
... 9 more
07-26 12:11:55.129   533  5923 E OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
07-26 12:11:55.525  1152  1958 E OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
07-26 12:11:55.607  1789  2879 E OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider: Failed to fetch suggestions from AppSearch, fallback to AGA
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:323)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:684)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:486)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2138)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:59)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.lambda$onResult$0(SearchSessionUtil.java:129)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.$r8$lambda$_nlk9WiPjSfaAsqKYmp0aPvSRC0(SearchSessionUtil.java:1)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:13)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider: Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:144)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:16)
07-26 12:11:55.646  1152  2300 E OneSearchSuggestProvider:        ... 8 more
07-26 12:11:57.005  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.games [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:57.005  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.maps#com.google.android.gms [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:57.005  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.cast [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:57.006  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.mobile_data_plan [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:57.006  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.udc [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:57.006  6716  7280 E PhenotypeRegOp: Attempting to overwrite config package for com.google.android.gms.vision [CONTEXT service_id=231 ]
07-26 12:11:57.723   533   827 E AppOps  : attributionTag VCN not declared in manifest of android
07-26 12:11:57.727   533   827 E AppOps  : attributionTag VCN not declared in manifest of android
07-26 12:11:57.741  1640  2118 E HwDetectorWithState: a: 3
07-26 12:11:57.776   533   827 E AppOps  : attributionTag VCN not declared in manifest of android
07-26 12:11:57.861   895  7497 E RoleControllerServiceImpl: Default/fallback role holder package doesn't qualify for the role, package: com.google.android.gms.supervision, role: android.app.role.SYSTEM_SUPERVISION
07-26 12:11:57.868   895  7497 E RoleControllerServiceImpl: Default/fallback role holder package doesn't qualify for the role, package: com.google.android.gms, role: android.app.role.SYSTEM_CALL_STREAMING
07-26 12:11:57.940   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f080107.
07-26 12:11:57.940   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f150560.
07-26 12:11:58.037   895   895 E AppsSafetyLabelHistoryP: File not found: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.permissioncontroller/files/apps_safety_label_history_persistence.xml
07-26 12:11:58.104  7510  7510 E android.youtube:
Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f080b16.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f140b44.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f080b14.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f140b06.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f080b18.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f140c52.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f080b12.
07-26 12:11:58.211   533   574 E system_server: No package ID 7f found for resource ID 0x7f14042f.
07-26 12:11:58.627   406   406 E BpTransactionCompletedListener: Failed to transact (-32)
07-26 12:11:58.628   406   406 E BpTransactionCompletedListener: Failed to transact (-32)
07-26 12:11:58.717   533   533 E JobServiceContext: Binding died for com.pickyassist.tb but no running job on this context
07-26 12:11:58.722   533   533 E JobServiceContext: Binding died for com.pi"

what did the crash report says?

I have provided the complete logcat when crashing. I believe the error message implies that the program crashes because it attempts to establish a foreground service without giving the proper foreground service type, but I have added these

Is that line (mentioned type) in the post above?
